# SQL - returning item ranking for data subset

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like some guidance on the best way to number subsets of data in my table and return the full dataset.

My dataset is about 50k records. The database holds test results and each row is an answer to a question. A person does 2 tests but these could be 2 of 20 or so tests.

The data looks like this:

```
PersonID    TestID    QuestionID
UID-1       T-1       QuA-1
UID-1       T-1       QuA-2
UID-1       T-1       QaA-3
UID-1       T-2       QuB-1
UID-1       T-2       QuB-2
UID-1       T-2       QuB-3
UID-2       T-1       QuA-1
UID-2       T-3       QuC-1
```

My aim is to return the dataset with a number to denote whether the test is the 1st or 2nd one the person did (the order is not important, I just need to allocate a 1 or 2 to their TestIDs). Likewise I need to number the questions as well.

Say a person does 2 tests, the first with 15 questions and the second with 20 questions, this is the output I would like:

```
PersonID    TestID    QuestionID   TestNum   QuNum
UID-1       T-1       QuA-1        1         1
UID-1       T-1       ...          1         ...
UID-1       T-1       QaA-15       1         15
UID-1       T-2       QuB-1        2         1
UID-1       T-2       ...          2         ...
UID-1       T-2       QuB-20       2         20
```

For each person the test number would either be 1 or 2 and the number of questions for a test would start at 1 and increase incrementally to the last question.

What approach would you use?

Comment: This sounds a little like an XY problem to me. What are you trying to do with the data once you get it? Is this something that can be more easily handled in the presentation layer rather than in the database engine? Or are you trying to then aggregate data based on this query?

Comment: It is the presentation issue that I was hoping these outputs could help with. I can do this in Excel but the cell references are large and it slows the file down dramatically. I was hoping there would be a way to do it in MySQL so that I could put the strain on the server rather than the local computer. In the presentation layer, have a single row per person with their question responses and overall scores set out in columns. I also use this single row per person dataset to do analysis on test statistics

Comment: Are you exporting this direct to excel, or is there some code in between? If you order the results on {PersonID asc, TestID asc, QuestionID asc}, you can simply increment counters and check each row's values against the previous one as you fetch rows from the result. Since you have to fetch the rows anyway, the overhead should be insignificant to store and compare values as data comes in.

Comment: I am exporting to Excel directly. The methodology you've outlined is in effect what I am doing in Excel currently. Could you expand a little more on counters? I am not strong in SQL. Would I need to use it in conjunction with CASE?

Comment: Sorry when I meant counters, I was talking normal procedural code. You could just as easily do this with VBA instead of trying to use formulas. Just loop through the rows once and keep track of the previous value. When TestID changes, increment TestNum and reset QuNum. When PersonID changes, reset both TestNum and QuNum.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. I have been trying to rework the workbook so macros wouldn't be necessary. Our team is good with Excel but not VBA. The outputs can change and our old macros break. Then it can take a while for the macros to be fixed. If I strip it back so this is the only bit where macros are used though it will still be a big improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the only way to do this in SQL is using "CURSORS".

Before declaring the cursor, I make a new table from the original one and add the two new columns (i.e., testNum and questionNum) with default values or 0 into it. This is done using "select into".

Then, reading the records of this table one by one (and ordered) by a cursor, I check if the personId and testId change or not and decide based on their status (update the two counters for current questionn and test).

At the end of the loop, before reading the next record, update the table using the two counters (for current question and current test).

Here's the code (BTW, I haven't test it. So take care of typos or possibly minor errors):

```
SELECT personId, testId, 0 as testNum, 0 as questionNum into t1
    FROM Questions

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT *
        FROM t1
        ORDER BY personId, testId, questionId
OPEN c1
declare @lastPersonId varchar(10);
declare @lastTestId varchar(10);
declare @currentTestNum int;
declare @currentQuestionNum int;

set @lastPersonId = "-1";
set @lastTestId = "-1";
set @currentTestNum = 1;
set @currentQuestionNum = 1;

FETCH NEXT FROM c1
    INTO @personId, @testId, @questionId, @testNum, @qNum

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    if (@personId <> @lastPersonId) 
        begin
        @currentTestNum = 1
        @currentQuestionNum = 1     
        end
    else
        if (@testId <> @lastTestId)         
            begin
            @currentTestNum = @currentTestNum + 1
            @currentQuestionNum = 1     
            end
        else -- in this case it is assumed that the questions are different.
            set @currentQuestionNum = @currentQuestionNum + 1

    update t1
        set testNum = @currentTestNum, questionNum = @currentQuestionNum
        where current of c1

    set @lastPersonId = @personId
    set @lastTestId = @testId
    FETCH NEXT FROM c1
        INTO @personId, @testId, @testNum, @qNum
    END  

CLOSE c1;
DEALLOCATE c1;
```